# Should I make sure that cloth simulated clothing is correct before I set up the movement of the character?

Tags: workflow, physics, cloth-simulation

I have a human model that wears a robe. I want to go ahead and set up the animation of what the model will do (e.g., walking, bending, sitting, picking up items) before I set up the cloth simulation for the robe (I am still learning about cloth simulation and do not yet know how to make it work well on a model that does any action other than walking.) If I set up the movement of the model and later set up the cloth simulation for his robe, will I run into any major problems?